# PHP Class 'COM' not found

Tags: php, windows, com

I am running Windows Server 2008 32-bit, PHP 5.4.5, and Apache 2.2.22.  I'm pretty sure COM is built-in to PHP core, but when I run the code to call a new COM object, I get a "Class 'COM' not found' error.  The COM object I am calling is Microsoft Word, which is installed.

The code:

```
$word = new COM("word.application") or die("Could not initiate Word COM Object.");
```

PHP just spits out the error as described above.

Comment: Chances are you don't have the 'com' module compiled, hit the phpinfo page and see if it's there.

Comment: Mike you are right - it is not in PHPInfo - but how is this possible?  All I did was download the ZIP file from PHP's website and extract it onto my disk.  How do I get a binary that has COM compiled within it?  I thought COM was a standard class as part of PHP Core as described here - http://www.php.net/manual/en/com.installation.php

Comment: From the comments [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/com.installation.php): _From PHP 5.4.5, COM and DOTNET is no longer built into the php core.you have to add COM support in php.ini_. (It does look like that PHP page needs updating - would you consider raising a bug ticket, Freddie?)

Comment: @halfer Please post that as an answer, this might be helpful for other users!

Comment: Thanks halfer - good find. +1

Comment: @halfer: Manual has edit link in the top-right corner. Better edit than bug-ticketing.

Comment: @hakre - thanks for that, I'd never noticed that before `:)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the user comments on the [PHP website](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/com.installation.php):

> From PHP 5.4.5, COM and DOTNET is no longer built into the php core. You have to add COM support in php.ini.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that this also exists from 5.3.15 and above, going by the below from the user comments:

> As of 5.3.15 (if you are still on 5.3 branch) you have to add
>   extension=php_com_dotnet.dll line into your php.ini to have COM,
>   DOTNET, VARIANT and similar classes available and working.
>
> From PHP Change log:
>
> ```
> COM
>
>     Fixed bug #62146 com_dotnet cannot be built shared
> ```
>
> Because of this, the official PHP builds for Windows are now built
>   with "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" option, which means no COM/DOTNET
>   support by default.